# How to cause "onmouseup" to function if the user drags the cursor off the div

Tags: javascript, onmousedown, onmouseup

Notice how if you `onmousedown`over the div, it turns from green to red. This is expected. But if you hold the mouse down and drag your cursor off and away from the div, then let go of your mouse, `onmouseup`won't function because the cursor is no longer hovering over the div. The div remains red instead of returning to its initial green state.

Should I use `onmousemove`?

Any ideas how to solve this?

```js
function mouseDown() {
    document.getElementById("test").style.backgroundColor = "red";
}

function mouseUp() {
    document.getElementById("test").style.backgroundColor = "green";
}
```

```css
#test {
position: absolute;
height: 50px;
width: 100px;
background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="test" onmousedown="mouseDown()" onmouseup="mouseUp()">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function mouseDown() {
    document.getElementById("test").style.backgroundColor = "red";
    document.getElementsByTagName("BODY").onmouseup = function() {mouseUp()};
}

function mouseUp() {
    document.getElementById("test").style.backgroundColor = "green";
}
```

```css
#test {
position: absolute;
height: 50px;
width: 100px;
background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div id="test" onmousedown="mouseDown()" onmouseup="mouseUp()" 
onmouseout="mouseUp()">
</div>
</body>
```

you should use `onmouseout()` which allow you to change content when mouse leave element.

here is a [link](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onmouseover) for more info

or you shoud use `mouseup` with parent element in our case div  element with `id=full` look here

```js
function mouseDown() {
          document.getElementById("test").style.backgroundColor = "red";
      }

      function mouseUp() {
          document.getElementById("test").style.backgroundColor = "green";
      }
```

```css
  #test {
    position: absolute;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: green;
    }
  #full{
      width: 100%;
      height: 2000px;
      background: blue;
    }
```

```html
<body>
<div id="full" onmouseup="mouseUp()" >

    <div id="test" onmousedown="mouseDown()" onmouseup="mouseUp()">
  </div>
  
</div>
  

</body>
```

Comment: you can also use onmouseup() with body element it is also work thank you for this question. i learn lots things. i hope you figure out. ;-)

Comment: Yes, this works. This is very thorough and complete answer, and beyond. Thank you!